# OpenCV feature pairs to point cloud

Tags: python, opencv

I have some SIFT features in two stereo images, and I'm trying to place them in 3D space. I've found triangulatePoints, which seems to be what I want, however, I'm having trouble with the arguments.

triangulatePoints takes 4 arguments, projMatr1 and projMatr2, which is where my issues start, and projPoints1 and projPoints2, which are my feature points. The OpenCV docs suggest using stereoRectify to find the projection matrices.

stereoRectify takes the intrinsic camera matrices (which I've calculated prior with calibrateCamera) and the image size from calibration. As well as two arguments R (rotation matrix) and T (translation vector), which can be found with stereoCalibrate.

However, stereoCalibrate takes "object points", which I'm pretty sure I can't calculate for images without a reference, which is a bit of a roadblock.

Is this the best way to be calculating 3D positions from pairs of features? If so, how can I calculate projMatr1 and projMatr2 without stereoCalibrate?

Comment: Notes: I'm using unfiltered SIFT points, so some of them are inaccurate. I don't have a proper stereo setup - this is just me taking a photo from two slightly offset positions.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you have no calibration, so let’s forget about rectification. What you want is the depth of the points, so you can project them into 3D (which then uses just the intrinsic calibration of one camera, mainly the focal length).

Since you have no rectification, you cannot expect exact results, so let’s try to get as close as possible:

Depth is focal length times baseline divided by disparity, disparity and focal length being in pixels, and depth and baseline in (recommendation) meters.

For accurate disparity you need a rectified camera and correspondences between your features in both images. Since without calibration, you have no hope of rectification, you could try to just use the original images instead. It will work fine the more parallel the cameras are. If they are not parallel, you will introduce an error here and your results will become less accurate. If this becomes bad you must find a way to calibrate your camera.

But most importantly, you need correspondences between your features in both images. Running SIFT in both images won‘t do. A better approach would be running SIFT in just one image and then finding the corresponding pixels for each of the features in the other image. There are plenty of methods for that, I believe OpenCv has some simple block matching builtin.